# Dynamic-DynamoDB is not scaling up, when I run as a sub process in the python code

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have used dynamic-dynamodb module in our restore script as an autoscaling option.
We often get throttle exception while running the restore script, but the dynamic-dynamodb module (which is running as a sub-process in the same code) is not autoscaling the write units. Attached are some of the useful screenshots.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic DynamoDB checks the provisioned and consumed throughput of your table periodically. You will need to sustain the load getting throttled for at least twice the [check interval](https://dynamic-dynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to guarantee that Dynamic DynamoDB will notice the throttling, per the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). To increase the sensitivity of your Dynamic DynamoDB configuration, reduce the check interval.